# QGraphicsItem setShear ? (applicable for single or multiple items)

Tags: qt, transformation, qgraphicsitem

To apply rotation on a QGraphicsItem, I can either call `rotate()` or `setRotation()`. What I see happening:

```
item.rotate(angle);
```

results in rotation, as I expect; yet if I copy the item (using a cop constructor in a subclass), no rotation will be copied (even if I copy all transformations).

```
item.setRotation(angle);
```

results in the item having a `rotation()` property which I can copy - but requires an update.

So the second version is what I need.

I would like to be able to apply shear to my items as well.

```
item.shear(shx, shy);
```

looks good on initial item - but I cannot find a way to copy this shear. Nor can I find a similar property as for rotation: there is no `setShear()` that I can find.

Even more, if I try to play with transformations, to achieve a group shear (like this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673574/1217150) rotation), I get very weird results...

How can I create a similar stored property for shear ?

Edit:

Trying

```
QTransform t;
t.shear(shx, shy);
item->setTransform(t, true);
```

also gives me a giant scaling and some rotation... I have tried to divide `shx` and `shy` by 100 and it seems reasonable (not sure if correct ?).

Note - will move the code snippet in answer, since it seems it will work.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at using void QGraphicsItem::setTransform(const QTransform & matrix, bool combine = false). Where the QTransform is constructed using a Shear matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix.

Comment: You said "even if I copy all transformations" - that's problematic, unless you misspoke. There is only one transformation, stored as a matrix, if you copy it piecewise, you are very likely to have a damaged copy.

Comment: @KubaOber What I meant is, when I create an item copy, I also do `copy->setTransform(original->transform());  copy->setRotation(original->rotation());...`

Comment: Avoid `setRotation` and similar methods, and only use `setTransform()`/`transform()` methods to get consistent behavior.

Comment: I was wrong. The graphics item class stores things quite redundantly: there's the `transform()`, represented as a matrix - this can do rotation, scaling, etc., but *on top of that* you also have `rotation()`, `scale()`, etc. These are all combined to obtain the effective transform for the item. This should work - the copy should have the same behavior as the original, as long as it has the same parent. If it doesn't, you're doing something wrong in code that you're not showing us. Please show us a minimum example that reproduces the problem (just a single main.cpp, please).

Comment: Also note that `setShear` is a compatibility member that you shouldn't be using. You'd need to look at how it's implemented, perhaps it's already stored inside of the `transform()` (whereas `scale()` and `rotation()` aren't)? Also, *do not* use `rotate()`, use `setRotation()`, unless you explicitly want to add to existing rotation. `rotate()` adds or subtracts a relative angle of rotation, `setRotation` sets the absolute angle of rotation.

Comment: @KubaOber setShear doesn't exist unfortunately - that was one of the points of the question. Unlike rotation, which has both rotate() and setRotation() - there is no simple transformation to set shear. I also did NOT say that my items don't copy correctly - I said that I DO COPY transformations, that is one of the requirements. It does seem now that I got it to work - though it seems wrong and somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have to divide shear factors by 100 (this doesn't seem true always).

```
void shearItem(qreal shx, qreal shy)
{
    QRectF rect;
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
        rect |= item->mapToScene(item->boundingRect()).boundingRect();    
    QPointF center = rect.center();

    QTransform t;

    t.translate(center.x(), center.y());
    // seems shear increases item to gigantic proportions so I tried
    t.shear(shx/100, shy/100);
    t.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
    {
        item->setPos(t.map(item->pos()));
        item->setTransform(t, true);
    }
}
```

I think the transformations are combined on item, so I don't need to do any action to combine any rotation or scaling or shear... I can just use

```
item->setTransform(t, true);
```

for all transforms so there is no need to separately set rotation or scale.

There does not seem to exist any conflict though between `translate()`, `rotate()`, `scale()` and `shear()` methods and setting the transform matrix. So combining these functions, and then copying the transform seems fine. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtransform.html#setMatrix).

There does not seem to be any documented reason for having to scale down the shear factors... (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtransform.html#shear).
If I set shear in item constructor, it works without having to divide by 100.
Yet if I call a shear as in code above, without scaling the factors down I get a resize as well. I find this very confusing... But as long as it works....

Full sample code: included rotation change and shear change

myview.h

```
#ifndef MYVIEW_H
#define MYVIEW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QAction>
#include <QContextMenuEvent>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class MyView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyView(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);

private slots:
    void rotateItem(qreal deg = 10);
    void shearItem(qreal shx = 10, qreal shy = 10);

private:
    void createActions();
    QAction *rotateAct;
    QAction *shearAct;
};

#endif // MYVIEW_H
```

myview.cpp

```
#include "myview.h"
#include <QMenu>

MyView::MyView(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    createActions();
    setScene(new QGraphicsScene(-500, -150, 1000, 600, this));
    setDragMode(RubberBandDrag);
}

void MyView::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsItem* item = itemAt(event->pos());
    if(item != NULL)
        item->setSelected(true);

    if(scene()->selectedItems().isEmpty())  return;

    QMenu menu(this);
    menu.addAction(rotateAct);
    menu.addAction(shearAct);
    menu.exec(event->globalPos());
}

void MyView::rotateItem(qreal deg)
{
    QRectF rect;
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
        rect |= item->mapToScene(item->boundingRect()).boundingRect();    
    QPointF center = rect.center();

    QTransform t;
    t.translate(center.x(), center.y());
    t.rotate(deg);
    t.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
    {
        item->setPos(t.map(item->pos()));
        item->setRotation(item->rotation() + deg);
    }
}

void MyView::shearItem(qreal shx, qreal shy)
{
    QRectF rect;
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
        rect |= item->mapToScene(item->boundingRect()).boundingRect();    
    QPointF center = rect.center();

    QTransform t;

    t.translate(center.x(), center.y());
    t.shear(shx, shy);
    // seems shear increases item to gigantic proportions so I tried
    //t.shear(shx/100, shy/100);
    t.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, scene()->selectedItems())
    {
        item->setPos(t.map(item->pos()));
        item->setTransform(t, true);
    }
}

void MyView::createActions()
{
    rotateAct = new QAction(tr("Rotate 10 degrees"), this);
    connect(rotateAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(rotateItem()));
    shearAct = new QAction(tr("Shear 10, 10"), this);
    connect(shearAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(shearItem()));
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>    
#include "myview.h"    

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyView* view = new MyView();

    QGraphicsRectItem* rItem = view->scene()->addRect(30, 40, 100, 100, Qt::NoPen, Qt::blue);
    QGraphicsRectItem* rItem1 = view->scene()->addRect(-30, -40, 100, 100, Qt::NoPen, Qt::red);
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* eItem = view->scene()->addEllipse(70, -50, 100, 100, Qt::NoPen, Qt::blue);

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, view->scene()->items())
    {
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    }

    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```